# See image generated in docker

Tags: docker

I created a Docker like:

```
FROM rikorose/gcc-cmake

RUN git clone https://github.com/hect1995/UBIMET_Challenge.git

WORKDIR /UBIMET_Challenge

RUN mkdir build

WORKDIR build

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cmake=3.13.1-1ubuntu3 protobuf-compiler

RUN cmake ..

RUN make
```

Afterwards I do:

```
docker build --tag trial .
docker run -t -i trial /bin/bash
```

Then I run an executable that saves a .png file inside the container.

How can I visualize the image?

Comment: What do you mean by "visualise" image?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute something inside the container.

To see all containers you can run `docker ps --all`.

To execute something inside container you can run `docker exec <container id> command`.

Otherwise you can copy files from container to host, with `docker cp <container id>:/file-path ~/target/file-path`

Answer (score 0):

Please mount a localhost volume(directory) with container volume(directory) in where you are saving your images.
now all of your images saved in container directory will be available in host or localhost mount directory. From there you can visualize or download to another machine.

Please follow this

```
docker run  --rm -d -v host_volume_or-directory:container_volume_direcotory trial
docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash
```